# Passivizing causative "make" - 'be made shudder'?

Tags: complementation, passive-voice, causative-make

Rewrite it in the passive:
*"These odds would make a professional  player shudder"*
I would do it as follows:"A professional  player would be made shudder by these odds". This sounds clumsy to me, so I'm not sure if I rewrote it correctly. Could you check it?

Rewrite these sentences using suitable forms of *make*:

> *1."We were obliged to clean up the mess we had made";*
>
> *2."The prisoners-of-war were obliged to build roads across the Burmese jungle".*

I would write:"We were made to clean up the mess we had made" and "The prisoners-of-war were made to build roads across the Burmese jungle", but in the example there's no "to" when "made" is used (When we were children, mother obliged us to take a bath every day - When we were children, mother made us take a bath every day). But to me it doesn't sound right without to. And take "bullies were threatening little boys" as an example how on earth would that change? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you **made** someone **do** something, that someone was **made to do** that something. Check this out: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/make#make_42 (sense 5, "to force someone to do something").

Comment: @Egghead99. As a tip, you can just write `[edit]` in comments, and it turns into a link: [edit].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You observe, correctly, that a verb which takes an infinitive ‘marked’ with *to* in the active voice also takes a marked infinitive in the passive voice.

```
 Mother obliged us to take a bath every day.
                   ⇓
 We were obliged   to take a bath every day (by mother).
```

From this you draw the ***entirely reasonable*** conclusion that a verb which takes an **un**marked infinitive in the active voice likewise takes an **un**marked infinitive in the passive voice.

```
 Mother made us ∅ take a bath every day.
                ⇓
 We were made   ∅ take a bath every day (by mother).
```

Alas, in this case (as in so many cases), English is ***unreasonable***. In the passive voice, almost all verbs which take unmarked infinitives<sup>†</sup> require a **marked** infinitive.

```
 Mother made us ∅ take a bath every day.
                ⇓
 We were made   to take a bath every day (by mother).
```

Consequently you must say

> A professional player would be made ***to*** shudder by these odds.

It’s just one of those things English instituted after the Norman Conquest to make the language as difficult as possible to learn. But it's a lot easier than mastering English spelling.

---

<sup>†</sup> There's only a handful of these verbs. Many of them cannot be passivized in the senses which permit unmarked infinitives: modals and semi-modals, auxiliary *do*, and causative *have* (as in *Mother had us take a bath*). With one exception, those that can be passivized— coercive *make*,*know*, *help* and the perception verbs *feel*, *hear*, *notice*, *observe*, *see* and *watch*—require marked infinitives in the passive. Only *let* allows an unmarked infinitive; and except in the collocation *let go*, *let* is rarely passivized today. The same thing appears to be happening with *make*, as Tim Romano’s answer suggests.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure of your question. But the differences are:

> {Someone|something} made us {infinitive form of the verb without "to"}.
>
> We were made {infinitive form of the verb with "to"} by {someone, something}.

So:

> Mother made us clean our rooms.
>
> We were made to clean our rooms by mother.

**These odds would make a professional player shudder.**

The exercise to rewrite the above in the passive voice would yield:

> A professional player would be made to shudder by these odds.

Although that might be idiomatic British usage (I'm not sure it is), idiomatic American is:

> A professional player would shudder *at* these odds.

**Made to {xxx}** is verbose, bordering on pompous, in the US of A.

> I shudder at the thought of being made to shudder at the thought.