# What does it mean? "in this film he is made to look very handsome indeed"

Tags: meaning, passive-voice

I have been listening to and reading [Luke's English Podcast](http://teacherluke.co.uk/2009/04/24/episode-5-vampires/) and I am not sure what the following sentence means:

> **in this film he is made to look very handsome indeed**

My guesses:

1. He is very good looking in the film.
2. The people who are making the movie made him very handsome.

Or does it mean anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess #2 is closer to what I would say it means. The sentence uses [the passive voice and the causative verb *make*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33560/passivizing-causative-make-be-made-shudder); this implies an external agent did something to cause Robert Pattinson to look handsome in *Twilight.* (This logically implies that #1 is true as well.)